# Launching Steam game on KDE on different GPU

Tags: kubuntu, intel-graphics, steam, amd-graphics

I'm running Kubuntu 21.10 under Xorg on an Intel Hades Canyon NUC - model [NUC8i7HVK](https://www.intel.co.uk/content/www/uk/en/products/sku/126143/intel-nuc-kit-nuc8i7hvk/specifications.html).
It contains two GPUs, one Intel and one AMD. In general desktop use on the Intel GPU is fine.

By default the desktop launches using the Intel GPU. Playing games in Steam, I don't get great framerates. I know the AMD GPU is slightly better at that.

**How do I make Steam (and all subsequent game launches) use the AMD GPU?**

```bsh
alan@robot:~$ switcherooctl list
Device: 0
  Name:        Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD®/ATI] Polaris 22 XT [Radeon RX Vega M GH]
  Default:     yes
  Environment: DRI_PRIME=pci-0000_01_00_0

Device: 1
  Name:        Intel® HD Graphics 630
  Default:     no
  Environment: DRI_PRIME=pci-0000_00_02_0
```

```bsh
alan@robot:~$ DRI_PRIME=0 glxinfo | grep vendor
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
OpenGL vendor string: AMD
```

```bsh
alan@robot:~$ DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep vendor
server glx vendor string: SGI
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
```

The Steam desktop file in `/usr/share/applications/steam.desktop` contains:

```
PrefersNonDefaultGPU=true
X-KDE-RunOnDiscreteGpu=true
```

I have tried running:

```
DRI_PRIME=0 steam
```

But that didn't appear to work as the game I played ([TrackMania² Stadium](https://store.steampowered.com/app/232910/TrackMania_Stadium/) (under Proton, in case it matters)) shows the GPU as Intel, not AMD.

Edit: I have also tried setting `DXVK_FILTER_DEVICE_NAME=POLARIS22` in the launch arguments in Steam. The game fails to launch correctly with that. A window appears then disappears.

Further, I gathered a log file via proton with: `DRI_PRIME=0 DXVK_FILTER_DEVICE_NAME=POLARIS22 PROTON_LOG=1 %command%` as the launch options. Log is [here](https://pastebin.com/hEyp11SM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need the correct codename for the Radeon RX Vega M GH, which, according to https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/radeon-rx-vega-m-gh.c3056 and `vulkaninfo | grep deviceName` should be `VEGAM`

Thus:

`DRI_PRIME=0 DXVK_FILTER_DEVICE_NAME="VEGAM" PROTON_LOG=1 %command%`

(`PROTON_LOG=1` thrown in to chuck a log in `$HOME` in case it fails)

should force it to use the Radeon.