# Ubuntu will not use my GPU

Tags: graphics, gpu

Guys I Have been researching for days on how to get this working. I have just started back with a fresh install to fix any nonsense that may have been messed up in the mean time, Now as far as i'm aware, DRI_PRIME=1 is 'supposed' to make the DGPU the primary if you use that line of code before running a program.
lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' shows

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)
DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
Subsystem: Dell Latitude E7470
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X] (rev e5)
Subsystem: Dell Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X]
Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
```

so the system "sees" my gpu , just wont use it .

: $DRI_PRIME=1 glxinfo | grep "OpenGL renderer"

```
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (SKL GT2)
```

im on Kernel Linux 6.2.0-20-generic Ubuntu 23.04 Wayland

Guys i downgraded to LTS and immediately ran DRI_PRIME=1 before running any updates and it recognizes the card ..... I am horribly unsure why some OS's will do this and others wont as i have tried many distros . but i will not complain .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Launching Steam game on KDE on different GPU](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391295/launching-steam-game-on-kde-on-different-gpu)

Comment: I linked to a question I asked a year ago. It has some tips which may help. At the time I had a system with two GPUs like you, a NUC. I had to use some commands to interrogate the GPUs, which you'll find in the question and answer, and may help.

Comment: (don't use Wayland would be my first step)

Comment: im switching to LTS real quick , will continue trying there

Comment: What is the output of `cat /etc/default/grub`? Sometimes it could be in nomodeset and could be preventing you from booting.

Comment: UEFI should have a seting on which graphics is default. Make sure that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Used to be setting the power option to "performance" would set the DGPU as primary, but one day, my CUDA samples stopped working, because the demos were trying to run on the Intel GPU.
A laptop is typically in hybrid mode, the DGPU does the hard work, and hands off to the Intel GPU for the display.  See the output of xrandr when running X (the modeseting is the Intel):

```
 $ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x45 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x26e cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 6 associated providers: 1 name:NVIDIA-G0
```

or maybe it looks like:

```
$ xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x1b7 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 6 associated providers: 1 name:NVIDIA-0
Provider 1: id: 0x1e7 cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
```

The first seems the source and sink are reversed, and need the
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia
environment variables which may be used in front of a program you want to force to use the nvidia.

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia <prog>
```